# Why do I see my entire react app in Chrome's Source tab

Tags: reactjs

I can see my entire react app(with same directory and filenames) on Google chrome's Sources tab.

Why is it so?

I tried this both in dev and production:

In dev:

```
npm start
```

prod:

```
yarn global add serve
serve -s build
```

I can see the entire architecture and files, routing/ rendering logic.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or maybe if could explain how a react server returns.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to make sure you are actually building a production build.

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p;",
```

I have seen no error with webpack but it infact didn't minify it.

Also, you will need to uglify() your production build to minify all code to computer only readable and in order to get the "blue production build" react logo if someone is using react dev tools in chrome, which is what I think you are looking to do.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

Here is an example of a webpack config I use. There are obviously things here you don't need.

```
    'use strict';

require('dotenv').config({ path: `${__dirname}/src/.dev.env` });
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const { DefinePlugin, EnvironmentPlugin } = require('webpack');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

let plugins = [
  new EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV']),
  new ExtractPlugin('bundle-[hash].css'),
  new HtmlPlugin({ template: `${__dirname}/src/index.html` }),
  new DefinePlugin({
    __DEBUG__: JSON.stringify(!production),
    __API_URL__: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
    __GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID__: JSON.stringify(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID),
    __AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID__: JSON.stringify(process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID),
    __AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY__: JSON.stringify(process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY),
  }),
];

if(production) {
  plugins = plugins.concat([new CleanPlugin(), new UglifyPlugin()]);
}

module.exports = {
  plugins,
  entry: `${__dirname}/src/main.js`,
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  devtool: production ? undefined : 'eval',
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    filename: 'bundle-[hash].js',
    publicPath: process.env.CDN_URL,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|glyph|\.svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'font/[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tiff|svg)$/,
        exclude: /\.glyph.svg/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 6000,
              name: 'image/[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp3|aac|aiff|wav|flac|m4a|mp4|ogg)$/,
        exclude: /\.glyph.svg/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { name: 'audio/[name].[ext]' },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```